# Loading multiple WPF XAML resources from various assemblies programatically in less number of iterations

Tags: c#, wpf

Programatically, I want to load many resources (XAML) which are spread across multiple assemblies.

e.g. I want to load

- resources A, B, C from Assembly1
- resources P, Q, R from Assembly2
- resources X, Y, Z from Assembly3

In my `app.config` file, I can configure the names of the assemblies and the resources to fetch from them. `Application.LoadComponent` API helps in loading resources at run time; but but it has to be called for as many number of resources I have. So this API will be called 9 times in my example.

Is there any way where I can reduce number of calls? I mean there will 3 different calls to 3 assemblies; but when one assembly is loaded all specified resources from that assembly should be loaded.

Does anyone know something of this sort?

Comment: What is the concern here? Performance? If so, why? Have you measured and found an issue?

Comment: @KentBoogaart: Good question. Performance is not a concern and I have not measured it either. But it looks logical to have assembly loaded once to load resources in it. So I am curious to know if someone has any solution for it.

Comment: That's the thing - the assembly *is* only loaded once. `LoadComponent` does not re-load the assembly each time.

Comment: @KentBoogaart : Oh! Thanks for this valuable info. Could you please share some link with me which describes this internal behavior of this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to search for any other API since the Application.Load API loads assembly only once in the AppDomain. Thanks to @Kent Boogaart for his comment to my question.